# Handle broken pipe on Java with SignalR

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Our Android app is using SignalR 5.0.0 (preview) to communicate with server. I'm getting a reported crash (related to app) with this error. I get that connection is getting dropped/cancelled/broke somehow but I don't see any reference in the documentation that can help with an approach how to handle this error. Any advice would be appreciated?

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x765d82cf08: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
       at io.reactivex.subjects.CompletableSubject.onError(CompletableSubject.java:131)
       at com.microsoft.signalr.OkHttpWebSocketWrapper$SignalRWebSocketListener.onFailure(OkHttpWebSocketWrapper.java:97)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:570)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.lambda$new$0$RealWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:161)
       at okhttp3.internal.ws.-$$Lambda$RealWebSocket$vImgSP5IPT4ir3b3bHxPQ53ps8k.run(:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Do you have a consistent repro and would you be willing to share it at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18925?

Comment: I cannot not reproduce it, I will upload the error stack in the issue if it helps to isolate it.